# Safari web inspector hide carriage return

Tags: safari, web-inspector

Safari's web inspector marks all the carriage returns in my Javascript file as red CR's. It's distracting - can I disable that?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In recent Safari Technology Preview builds, you can toggle this in the Settings tab. Try the options "Whitespace Characters" and "Invalid Characters".